# postfix calculator having trouble with segfaults

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, postfix-notation

i'm trying to create a postfix calculator using linked-list.
when i compile, it doesn't show any errors but when it's executed it would show Segmentation Fault. i don't know how to deal with this, please help.
here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct node {
    int num;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void push(int num, node **head);
int pop(node **head);
void display(node **head);
int is_empty();
int evaluatePostfix();

struct node *head;

int main()  {
    head = NULL;
    char exp[1000]; // = "5 1 2 + 4 * + 3 -";
    printf("Input expression:\t");
    fgets(exp, 1000, stdin);
    for(int i = 1; i <= strlen(exp); i++) {
        if(exp[i] == '\n') {
            exp[i] = '\0';
        }
        else if (exp[0] == '\n') {
            printf("stack is empty\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    printf("%s = %d\n", exp, evaluatePostfix(exp));

    return 0;
```

}

```
int evaluatePostfix(char* exp)  {
    char * token;
    int counter = 0;
    char temp[256][256];
    token = strtok(exp, " ");
    while(token != NULL)    {
        strcpy(temp[counter], token);
        counter++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");  
    }

    for (int i = 0; temp[i]; ++i)   {
        if (isdigit(*(temp[i]))) {
            int val = atoi(temp[i]);
            push(val, &head);
        }
        else   {
            int val1 = pop(&head);
            int val2 = pop(&head);
            switch (exp[i]) {
                case '+':    push(val2 + val1, &head);
                             printf("%d\n", (*head).num);
                             break;
                case '-':    push(val2 - val1, &head);    break;
                case '*':    push(val2 * val1, &head);    break;
                case '/':    push(val1 / val2, &head);    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pop(&head);
}


void push (int item, node **head) {
    node *temp;
    node * get_node(int);
    temp = get_node(item);
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;
}

node *get_node(int item) {
    node *temp;
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (temp == NULL)
        printf("\nMemory cannot be allocated");
    temp->num = item;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return(temp);
}


int pop(node **head)    {
    int item;
    node *temp;
    item = (*head)->num;
    temp = *head;
    *head = (*head)->next;
    free(temp);
    return(item);
}

int is_empty(node *temp) {
    if (temp == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}


void display(node **head)   {
    node *temp;
    temp = *head;
    if(head == NULL)    {
        printf("stack is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("=========\n");
    while(temp!=NULL)   {
        printf("%d\n", (*temp).num);
        temp = (*temp).next;
    }
    printf("=========\n");
}
```

Comment: It's a quite long piece of code to see the problem right away. You should use a debugger.

Comment: There are easier ways to removing the newline from a string read by `fgets` than your loop. If (and only if) `fgets` doesn't return a `NULL` pointer, then the possible newline will be at e.g. `exp[strlen(exp) - 1]`.

Comment: i think the problem is with evaluatePostfix( ) but i'm not really sure how to fix it. what debugger do you suggest?

Comment: Depends on what platform/toolchain you are using. The generic answer would be "gdb".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this declaration ...

```
char temp[256][256];
```

... the loop termination condition here is wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; temp[i]; ++i)   {
```

C multi-dimensional arrays are *not* Java-style arrays of array *references*.  They are arrays of actual arrays.  The expression `temp[i]` will not be false when `i` exceeds the number of elements of `temp[]` into which you have written data.

It looks like you want simply

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i)   {
```

.  Alternatively, there's no particular need to tokenize before your start the computation.  You could as easily combine the two loops in function `evaluatePostfix()` into one.  That would be a bit simpler, and would remove any fixed limit on the number of terms in the expression.

**Update:**  That might look like this:

```
for (token = strtok(exp, " "); token; token = strtok(NULL, " ")) {

    /* ... use token instead of temp[i] ... */

}
```

It is conceivable that there are other errors in your code as well, though I didn't spot any on my scan through it.

Comment: yes, i also tried to use for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i) but it also results a segfault.   what then do you suggest i can do to evaluate a string
eg. 5 1 2 + 4 * + 3 - without tokenizing?

Comment: I didn't say you could evaluate without tokenizing.  I said you could evaluate without tokenizing *separately*.  I have updated my answer to show how.

Comment: It is conceivable that you have one or more other errors that also cause a segfault despite the one I spotted being fixed.  In that case, the best way to sort this out would be your toolchain's debugger and/or a tool specific to identifying memory issues, such as valgrind.

Comment: i tried gdb and it showed this. i have no idea how to fix it. what do you suggest?    `Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access      memory.Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x0000000100000ba5 in pop (head=0x1000010e8) at ask.c:111
111           item = (*head)->num;`

Comment: The message appears to be telling you that you are trying to dereference a null pointer in the code corresponding to line 111 of file `ask.c` (the source of which it has helpfully printed for you).  Evidently either `head` or `*head` is null.  I don't at the moment see how that could happen with valid input, but it could *easily* happen with invalid input (when there are fewer than two operands on the stack at the time that you process an operator).  Perhaps the issue is related to the fact that your code does not support negative numbers in its input.

Answer (score 0):

"btw, all identifiers for functions in the Standard Library are reserved.
There is a function exp() in math.h, so exp falls into that category.
Technically, using a reserved identifier in your code results in undefined behaviour."

Thanks for the help guys! Changing exp to another variable name did the trick. here's the working code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct node {
    int num;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void push(int num, node **head);
int pop(node **head);
void display(node **head);
int is_empty(node *temp);
int evaluate(char *expression);

struct node *head;

int main()  {
    head = NULL;
    char expression[1000]; // = "5 1 2 + 4 * + 3 -";
    printf("Input expression:\t");
    fgets(expression, 1000, stdin);
    for(int i = 1; i <= strlen(expression); i++) {
        if(expression[i] == '\n') {
            expression[i] = '\0';
        }
        else if (expression[0] == '\n') {
            printf("empty stack\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    printf("Answer: %d\n", evaluate(expression) );
    return 0;
```

}

```
int evaluate(char* expression)  {
    char * token;
    int counter = 0;
    char temp[256][256];
    token = strtok(expression, " ");
    while(token != NULL)    {
        strcpy(temp[counter], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");  
        counter++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)   {
        if (isdigit(*(temp[i]))) {
            int val = atoi(temp[i]);
            push(val, &head);
        }
        else   {
            int val1 = pop(&head);   //pop the last two values from stack
            int val2 = pop(&head);
            switch (*(temp[i])) {    //perform operation
                case '+':    push(val2 + val1, &head);  break;
                case '-':    push(val2 - val1, &head);  break;
                case '*':    push(val2 * val1, &head);  break;
                case '/':    push(val1 / val2, &head);  break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pop(&head);
}

void push (int item, node **head) {
    node *temp;
    node * get_node(int);
    temp = get_node(item);
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;
}

node *get_node(int item) {
    node *temp;
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (temp == NULL)
        printf("\nMemory cannot be allocated");
    temp->num = item;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return(temp);
}

int pop(node **head)    {
    int item;
    node *temp;
    item = (*head)->num;
    temp = *head;
    *head = (*head)->next;
    free(temp);
    return(item);
}

int is_empty(node *temp) {
    if (temp == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void display(node **head)   {
    node *temp;
    temp = *head;
    if(head == NULL)    {
        printf("stack is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("=========\n");
    while(temp!=NULL)   {
        printf("%d\n", (*temp).num);
        temp = (*temp).next;
    }
    printf("=========\n");
}
```

Comment: "Technically, using a reserved identifier in your code results in undefined behaviour."  Yes, but the name of the standard library function `exp()` is reserved *only* as an identifier with external linkage.  Function arguments and local variables have *no* linkage.  Using `exp` as a local variable name does not produce UB.